# How movss opcode need to be interpreted?

Tags: assembly, x86-64, disassembly

I get this Disassembly code on Visual Studio IDE's Debugger, from a C++ build:

[image]

For what I see on [movss](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/movss) instruction, it should be

1. F3 0F 10 /r MOVSS xmm1, xmm2 -- Merge scalar single precision floating-point value from xmm2 to xmm1 register.
2. F3 0F 10 /r MOVSS xmm1, m32 - Load scalar single precision floating-point value from m32 to xmm1 register.
3. F3 0F 11 /r MOVSS xmm2/m32, xmm1 -- Move scalar single precision floating-point value from xmm1 register to xmm2/m32.

So, while first 3 bytes are easy to understand, I don't really understand the rest, such as `05 6b 02 10 00` for the first row, `44 24 38` for the second, and so on.

Can you help me to understand them? 05 or 44 seems /r? What does it means?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You will need the [official pdf version](https://cdrdv2.intel.com/v1/dl/getContent/671110) of the *Intel® 64 and IA-32 Architectures Software Developer's Manual Volume 2: Instruction Set Reference, A-Z*.

Consult the chapter *"3.1.1.1 Opcode Column in the Instruction Summary Table (Instructions without VEX Prefix)"* which says:

> /r Indicates that the ModR/M byte of the instruction contains a register operand and an r/m operand.

Then look in the *Table 2-2. 32-Bit Addressing Forms with the ModR/M Byte*, find the value `05`. It is in the `xmm0` column and the `disp32` row. This means a 32 bit displacement will follow. Finally see *Table 2-7. RIP-Relative Addressing* which says that `disp32` is repurposed to mean `RIP + Disp32` in 64 bit mode. Hence the `6B 02 10 00` mean `RIP + 0010026B` which is helpfully (?) decoded by the disassembler as `7FFB47521775 + 0010026B = 7FFB476219E0`

For the second instruction, you will find the `44` in column `xmm0`, row `[--][--]+disp8` which according to the footnote means:

> 1 . The [--][--] nomenclature means a SIB follows the ModR/M byte.
>
> 3 . The disp8 nomenclature denotes an 8-bit displacement that follows the ModR/M byte (or the SIB byte if one is present) and that is sign-extended and added to the index.

So the next byte is a SIB. You can see those in *Table 2-3. 32-Bit Addressing Forms with the SIB Byte*. The value `24` is in column `esp`, row `none`. Adjusting for 64 bit this means the address is in the form of `[rsp + disp8]` with the displacement given by the following byte which is `38`.